# ggplot2 hell with rpy2-2.0.7 + python 2.6 + r 2.11 (windows 7)

Tags: python, r, device, ggplot2, rpy2

i am using rpy2-2.0.7 (i need this to work with windows 7, and compiling the binaries for the newer rpy2 versions is a mess) to push a two-column dataframe into r, create a few layers in ggplot2, and output the image into a <.png>.

i have wasted countless hours fidgeting around with the syntax; i did manage to output the files i needed at one point, but (stupidly) did not notice and continued fidgeting around with my code ...

i would sincerely appreciate any help; below is a (trivial) example for demonstration.  Thank you very much for your help!!!   ~  Eric Butter

---

```
import rpy2.robjects as rob
from rpy2.robjects import r
import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
from array import array

r.library("grDevices")    # import r graphics package with rpy2
r.library("lattice")
r.library("ggplot2")
r.library("reshape")

picpath = 'foo.png' 

d1 = ["cat","dog","mouse"]
d2 = array('f',[1.0,2.0,3.0])

nums = rob.RVector(d2)
name = rob.StrVector(d1)

tl = rlc.TaggedList([nums, name], tags = ('nums', 'name'))
dataf = rob.RDataFrame(tl)

## r['png'](file=picpath, width=300, height=300)
## r['ggplot'](data=dataf)+r['aes_string'](x='nums')+r['geom_bar'](fill='name')+r['stat_bin'](binwidth=0.1)
r['ggplot'](data=dataf)
r['aes_string'](x='nums')
r['geom_bar'](fill='name')
r['stat_bin'](binwidth=0.1)
r['ggsave']()
## r['dev.off']()
```

*The output is just a blank image (181 b).

---

here are a couple common errors R itself throws as I fiddle around in ggplot2:

```
r['png'](file=picpath, width=300, height=300)
r['ggplot']()
r['layer'](dataf, x=nums, fill=name, geom="bar")
r['geom_histogram']()
r['stat_bin'](binwidth=0.1)
r['ggsave'](file=picpath)
r['dev.off']()
```

*RRuntimeError: Error: No layers in plot

```
r['png'](file=picpath, width=300, height=300)
r['ggplot'](data=dataf)
r['aes'](geom="bar")
r['geom_bar'](x=nums, fill=name)
r['stat_bin'](binwidth=0.1)
r['ggsave'](file=picpath)
r['dev.off']()
```

*RRuntimeError: Error: When *setting* aesthetics, they may only take one value. Problems: fill,x

Comment: Can you create the ggplot2 plot in R without all the python cruft around it? It might be easier to start with the R code and then after that works try converting that to RPy2. Having R wrapped in RPy2 calls makes an extra layer to debug through.

Comment: Use either `ggsave` OR `png()` + `dev.off()`.  You may also need to explicitly `print()` the plot.

Comment: Or just rewrite the Python part in R ;-)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions i will give them a try.  

haha and right now I am doing just that --> porting things directly to R for the analysis.  unfortunately, i "need" the python because this is a web app that i am developing with pylons.  

what i might do is get rid of most of the python and pull the data from my mssql rdms directly from r.

Comment: It might help you set the ggplot2 code right (looks like your issue is primarily).

Comment: I prefer to deal with actual R code as much as possible when using rpy2. I would write something like `r('pp<-ggplot()+data=dataf+aes_string…')`. Then `r('ggsave(pp,…)')` I tried wrangling with rpy2 for a bit but got frustrated. Now I just use it to transfer data back and forth and use pure Python or pure R as much as possible.

Comment: I don't know exactly how RPy2 handles variables that get created, but it doesn't look like you ever store the results of the call to `ggplot` in a variable so that you can `print` it later.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is also the `pyper` package for calling R from python. http://www.webarray.org/softwares/PypeR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use rpy2 solely through Nathaniel Smith's brilliant little module called [rnumpy](http://bitbucket.org/njs/rnumpy/wiki/API) (see the "API" link at the rnumpy home page). With this you can do:

```
from rnumpy import *

r.library("ggplot2")

picpath = 'foo.png' 
name = ["cat","dog","mouse"]
nums = [1.0,2.0,3.0]

r["dataf"] = r.data_frame(name=name, nums=nums)
r("p <- ggplot(dataf, aes(name, nums, fill=name)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')")
r.ggsave(picpath)
```

(I'm guessing a little about how you want the plot to look, but you get the idea.)

Another great convenience is entering "R mode" from Python with the ipy_rnumpy module. (See the "IPython integration" link at the rnumpy home page).

For complicated stuff, I usually prototype in R until I have the plotting commands worked out. Error reporting in rpy2 or rnumpy can get quite messy.

For instance, the result of an assignment (or other computation) is sometimes printed even when it should be invisible. This is annoying e.g. when assigning to large data frames. A quick workaround is to end the offending line with a trailing statement that evaluates to something short. For instance:

```
In [59] R> long <- 1:20
Out[59] R>
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [19]  19  20

In [60] R> long <- 1:100; 0
Out[60] R> [1] 0
```

(To silence some recurrent warnings in rnumpy, I've edited rnumpy.py to add 'from warnings import warn' and replace 'print "error in process_revents: ignored"' with 'warn("error in process_revents: ignored")'. That way, I only see the warning once per session.)

Comment: cool solution, Jon.  for reliability's sake, i decided not to build my application on top of multiple api's :) but this definitely works!  thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You have to engage the dev() before you shut it off, which means that you have to print() (like JD guesses above) prior to throwing dev.off().

```
from rpy2 import robjects                          
r = robjects.r                                                                                    
r.library("ggplot2")
robjects.r('p = ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()') 
r.ggsave('/stackBar.jpeg') 
robjects.r('print(p)')
r['dev.off']()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it slightly more easy when you have to draw more complex plots:

```
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
r = robjects.r
grdevices = importr('grDevices')
p = r('''
  library(ggplot2)

  p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar()
  p <- p + opts(title = "{0}")
    # add more R code if necessary e.g. p <- p + layer(..)
  p'''.format("stackbar")) 
  # you can use format to transfer variables into R
  # use var.r_repr() in case it involves a robject like a vector or data.frame
p.plot()
# grdevices.dev_off()
```